# How to popup a grid in kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have checked many documentations and questions here. But all of them are using edit template in grid, and popup a customer window. My scenario is I define a template in one of my column, a button beside the really value. When I click the button, popup a kendo-grid, which data source has already exit in parent grid's datasource. Any solutions?

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what are you trying to achieve. Please explain in more detail and more clearly.

Comment: I just wanto click a button to popup a window, the window's content is a kendo grid, the grid's data is passed through the parameter of click function.